# Unable to CREATE TRIGGER in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, database-trigger

The database simply hangs and never provides an error or response.  I've tried this in pgadmin and pgsql.

The trigger is to refresh a materialized view.  My trigger function for the refresh has inserted successfully, but I cannot create the trigger.

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig_refresh_inprogress() RETURNS trigger 
AS
$$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY inprogress;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_01_refresh_inprogress 
   AFTER TRUNCATE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON customer FOR EACH STATEMENT
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_refresh_inprogress();
```

I have verified that I have trigger privileges on the customer table and executive privileges on the function.

Comment: Probably you need dynamic sql: `execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY inprogress;';`

Comment: In the trigger or in the function?